# Assignation: pass argument to the function

Tags: php, smarty

Having `php` code:

```
function getChildren($parent_id = 0)
{
....
return $SomeChildrenArray;
}
```

And Smarty assignation `$smarty->assign('children', getChildren($id));`

How to write smarty expression to pass some value to the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty can be extended through its plugins API. See [registerPlugin()](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl) for an introduction.

```
$smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'children', function($params, $template) {
  return "some string:" . $params['foobar'];
});
```

and

```
{children foobar="hello world"}
```

would output

```
some string:hello world
```

Note that plugin functions have to return a string.

---

Since Smarty3 you can call and assign arbitrary functions from within a template:

```
{$children = getChildren(3)}
```

This way you can call any function and return any value/type you want. See [Smarty_Security](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl#advanced.features.security) for details on how to control which functions may be called…

Answer (score 0):

PHP file:

```
$smarty->assign('children', function($parent_id = 0) {
    ....
    return $SomeChildrenArray;
});
```

tpl file for parent_id=2

`{children p1=2}`

Comment: could `p1` assigned before like this `{assign var="p1" value="2"}`

Comment: The proposed solution leads to a SmartyCompilerException `unknown tag "children"`

Comment: @rodneyrehm maybe should be {$children p1=2}

Comment: Smarty 3.1.10 throws an exception saying `unexpected "p1" attribute'` for `{$children p1=2}`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry! I'am was wrong in my post =) Try this please

php file

```
$smarty->registerPlugin("function","my_supper_closure_function", "my_supper_closure_function");
function my_supper_closure_function($params, $smarty){
$SomeChildrenArray=array($params["parent_id"]);
return print_r($SomeChildrenArray,true);
}

$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

tpl file

```
{my_supper_closure_function parent_id=2}
```